# Структура проекта ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, view, model

Пытаюсь понять, как правильно писать приложения на ASP.NET MVC. Во всех примерах, что я видела, всегда создается одно представление для одной страницы. А представлению соответствует одна модель.
А если у меня на странице должно быть несколько элементов, у которого своя модель и свое (единообразное) представление. Например, несколько форм с одной кнопкой, которая обрабатывается одинаково. Т.е, такой массив связок модель-представление? Можно ли (правильно ли) размещать их на 1 странице? И какой при этом синтаксис?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Все правильно, одному представлению всегда соответсвует одна модель.
Если у Вас несколько форм на странице, главное чтобы у них были разные Id.

Но, насколько я понял из Вашего вопроса, вы хотите обработать на одной странице несколько объектов(моделей), при таком подходе, нужно создать отдельную модель представления(класс), который будет объединять в себе необходимое Вам количество объектов(моделей), и ее отправить в представление.
Т.е. моделью представления становится класс, в котором вы собрали необходимые для отображения и редактирования данные. В качестве бонуса, в Razor получаете Intellisence, и автоподстановку свойств объектов.

Думаю примеры излишни, все и так предельно просто. 
Что касается того, правильно/неправильно, приведите пример кода представления, можно будет предметно прокомментировать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59788/discussion-on-answer-by-ieshua---asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

можно почитать вот тут 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view

и тут с примером даже 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/WebControls/

и тут немного
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3

и тут

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1108855/ways-to-Bind-Multiple-Models-on-a-View-in-MVC